# Scrapy: decode request.see codes from crawlling history

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I have a `Scrapy` project that saves the crawling in a `JOBDIR`in order to prevent crawling of already seen URLs.

My problem is related to the fact that sometimes the crawling was not good in a particular URL for some reason and I need to fix the spider and run it again. Of course I do not want to re-crawl all urls but only that specific one that gave some problems.

I would like to localize the URL in the `request.seen` and just delete it, but is not possible because all URLs are coded.

How can I decode `request.seen` file to the original URLs?